# Циклы, loops, как работает цикл внутри цикла?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Cовсем недавно начал учить программирование на js, это мой первый 
ЯП, хотел бы у вас узнать как работают циклы внутри циклов, не могу сделать одну задачу (исключительно в учебных целях, копипаст мне не нужен, а толковое обьяснение, я здесь чтобы учится).

К примеру вот задача взята с learn.js.ru.

Не понимаю как ведет себя `j` внутри `i`

```js
nextPrime: for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j === 0) continue nextPrime;
        }
        alert(i);
    }
```

Надеюсь не заминусуете, спасибо если кто откликнется!

Comment: циклы внутри циклов работают так же как снаружи циклов. Что Вам непонятно?

Comment: Замените внутренний цикл  на `for (var j = 2; j < 10; j++)`, выведите на печать значения i и j и все сразу станет понятно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Зачем менять границу изменения `j`? Это будет другая задача.

Comment: Менять затем, чтобы понять как работает цикл внутри цикла. Задача тут вообще не при чем.

Comment: Все протестирую, чтобы закрепить , спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по очереди с комментариями в коде:

```
// Создаём цикл с названием nextPrime,
// где начальное значение - 2 (i = 2),
// максимальное значение - 9 (i < 10 = "<= 9")
nextPrime: for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {

    // Создаём ещё один цикл без названия,
    // где начальное значение - 2 (j = 2),
    // максимальное значение - "i - 1" (j < i),
    // т.е. из цикла выше (nextPrime)
    // мы при каждом проходе получаем значение i (i = 2, i = 3, i = 4 и т.д.)
    // и при каждом запуске этого внутреннего цикла -
    // запускаем его на промежутке от 2 до текущего значения i,
    // не включая его (2 <= j < i)
    for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {

        // Если текущий i кратен j (i % j),
        if (i % j === 0) {

            // то останавливаем дальнейшее выполнение данной итерации цикла `nextPrime`
            // (и все циклы, находящиеся внутри него)
            // и переходим к следующей итерации
            continue nextPrime;
        }
    }

    // Выводим alert с текущим значением i (из цикла nextPrime),
    // если данная итерация не была прервана при условии выше
    alert(i);
}
```

Для закрепления приведу пример выполнения с нумерацией циклов, где первое значение - i, второе значение (через точку) - j (т.е.: "**i.j)**":

- **3.2)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "3";
- **4.2)** Т.к. i % j = 0 (остаток от деления i на j) - то пропускаем данный цикл: `continue nextPrime;`
- **5.2)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "5";
- **5.3)** Т.к. i % j = 2 - выводим алерт со значением "5";
- **5.4)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "5";
- **6.2)** Т.к. i % j = 0 - то пропускаем данный цикл: `continue nextPrime;`
- **7.2)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "7";
- **7.3)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "7";
- **7.4)** Т.к. i % j = 3 - выводим алерт со значением "7";
- **7.5)** Т.к. i % j = 2 - выводим алерт со значением "7";
- **7.6)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "7";
- **8.2)** Т.к. i % j = 0 - то пропускаем данный цикл: `continue nextPrime;`
- **9.2)** Т.к. i % j = 1 - выводим алерт со значением "9";
- **9.3)** Т.к. i % j = 0 - то пропускаем данный цикл: `continue nextPrime;`

Comment: Спасибо большое все разобрал!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так понятнее?

```js
console.log("Начинаем внешний цикл");
nextPrime: for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("  Итерация внешнего цикла. i = " + i);
  if (2 < i)
    console.log("  Начинаем внутренний цикл");
  for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    console.log("    Итерация внутреннего цикла. j = " + j + ", i = " + i);
    if (i % j === 0) {
      console.log("    Условие (i % j === 0) выполнено. запускаем новую итерацию внешнего цикла");
      continue nextPrime;
    }
  }
  // alert(i);
  console.log("  Закончили внутренний цикл. i = " + i);
}

console.log("Закончили внешний цикл");
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение , разобрался!!